# Using operator functions outside the context of an argument in Swift

Tags: swift

So, when declaring a closure, we can get pretty abstract.  For example, we could do a sort with an inline closure like:

```
var arr = sort(["a", "b", "c"], { $0 > $1 }) // Shows ["c", "b", "a"]
arr
```

Which could then be simplified to an operator function like this:

```
var arr = sort(["a", "b", "c"], >) // Shows ["c", "b", "a"]
arr
```

Because:

> Swift’s String type defines its string-specific implementation of the greater-than operator (>) as a function that has two parameters of type String, and returns a value of type Bool. This exactly matches the function type needed for the sort function’s second parameter. Therefore, you can simply pass in the greater-than operator, and Swift will infer that you want to use its string-specific implementation

However, I can't seem to find a way to do this outside of the context of that argument.  When it's being passed as an argument, '>' is almost like the name of a function that is associated with 'String'.  In that way, I would think it should be possible to assign outside the context of the argument.  For example, is there some way I could do this:

```
var inlineClosure: (String, String) -> Bool = { > }

// or
var inlineClosure: (String, String) -> Bool = >
```

This is purely experimental, I am just curious if it is possible.

#### Note

This question isn't about how to assign an inline closure in any way other than as an operator.  I'm already familiar with various declaration types, including shorthand arguments & trailing closures.  I'm specifically looking for a way to do this by only assigning an operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
let f : (String, String) -> Bool = (>)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with Xcode. You can get it to work though. Type out the whole line like you did:

```
var inlineClosure: (String, String) -> Bool = { > }
```

Then delete and retype the operator. For some reason that allows the parser to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hmm, I was able to silence the warning that way, but I can't then use the closure as I'd like to: `inlineClosure("a", "b")`.  It doesn't return anything and everything below it in my playground no longer executes.  Can you confirm that you were able to return a value that way?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
var inlineClosure: (String, String) -> Bool = { $0 > $1 }
```

Comment: I already know how to do that, that's not really what I'm asking for.  Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign `inlineClosure` with an actual closure with:

```
  7> var inlineClosure = { (a:String, b:String) -> Bool in return a > b }
inlineClosure: (String, String) -> Bool =
  8> inlineClosure ("a", "b")
$R3: Bool = false
  9> inlineClosure ("c", "b")
$R4: Bool = true
```

BTW, there is special syntax for a method that has a closure as the last argument:

```
var answer = sort ([1,3,2]) { (a:Int, b:Int) -> Bool in return a < b }
```

Convenient that.

Comment: Yea, I already know how to do all of those, maybe I should edit my question to avoid confusion.  Thanks for your answer.